# Anaconda 4.6.11: Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has not been activated

Tags: python, environment-variables, python3, anaconda

Although I have been using **Anaconda** for some time, the latest version has introduced some interesting behavior that I had not experienced.

1. First, there is a warning showing up.

   > *WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.*

   **I have heard that this will be removed in next version, but if someone can confirm this, that would be great!**

---

2. Secondly, and most importantly, in previous versions, I could type '***python***' into the command line in order to get the python interpreter. However, after going to this anaconda version installation, the following warning has been popping up:

   > Warning:
   >   This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has
   >   not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this environment
   >   please see https://conda.io/activation

   **I have looked through the website, yet nothing has worked for me. When I type in *'conda activate'* and then run *'python'*, there is no warning; however, I did not have to do that in the past.**

**NOTE: I installed anaconda for all users. The path and variables are below. My user variables have nothing related to anaconda as it was a system installation.**

[image: Environment Variables]
[image: Print Statement Environment Variables]

Any suggestions?
Thank you, and please let me know if you need any clarification!

Comment: This creates a huge problem to me, as I am no longer able to embed a Python interpreter created by conda into my app: Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'. This worked with environments created by previous version of conda.

Answer (score -1):

on which OS are you working?

Can you print your environment variables?

Looks like the python environment variable has been overwritten with the anaconda.

Comment: I am working with Windows 10 Pro. I have added a screenshot in the post of a print of my environment variables. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I find out the problem. Please see the following. I am thinking it is a env config issue. I am figuring how to directly start Python from C:\Users\Administrator>python. Once I have any update, I will update it to you.

Warning:
This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has
not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this environment
please see https://conda.io/activation

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > >

C:\Users\Administrator>conda activate base

(base) C:\Users\Administrator>conda activate

(base) C:\Users\Administrator>python
Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 17:13:21) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.